# Is there a version of setTimeout that returns an ES6 promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout), but rather than asking about how promises work in general, I specifically want to know:

What is the standard/best way to wrap [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) in something that returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?  I'm thinking something like Angular's [`$timeout` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), but not Angular specific.

Comment: Didn't see this one, here's how I'd do it -> http://jsfiddle.net/vLtrtoLL/

Comment: The Bluebird promise library has `Promise.delay()`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### In Browsers

First of all no - there is no built in for this. Lots of libraries that enhance ES2015 promises like bluebird whip with it.

I think the other answer conflates executing the function and a delay, it also creates timeouts that are impossible to cancel. I'd write it simply as:

```
function delay(ms){
    var ctr, rej, p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ctr = setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        rej = reject;
    });
    p.cancel = function(){ clearTimeout(ctr); rej(Error("Cancelled"))};
    return p; 
}
```

Then you can do:

```
delay(1000).then(/* ... do whatever */);
```

Or

```
 doSomething().then(function(){ return delay(1000); }).then(doSomethingElse);
```

If we only want the basic functionality in ES2015, it's even simpler as:

```
let delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
```

### In Node

You can use `util.promisify` on `setTimeout` to get a `delay` function back - meaning you don't have to use the `new Promise` constructor anymore.

Comment: Beautiful answer. I'm totally glad I asked the question now.

Comment: Problem with this example: `clearTimeout` should be called when resolving also.

Comment: when I try either version of @Benjamin Gruenbaum's answer above, the code following then( executes immediately without waiting for the delay.  Example `delay(2000).then(console.log("then 1")).then(delay(2000).then(console.log("then 2")));` prints both "then 1" "then 2" immediately with no delay, two seconds later the program finishes.

Comment: @TimothyVann `then` takes a function - not a promise.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd implement it:

```
function delay(duration, func) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);

  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(func.apply(null, args));
    }, duration);
  });
}
```

(ES5-syntax intentionally chosen)

But maybe there's a common library that already does this, or a better way to do it.

Comment: This looks fine. It's such a short piece of code that I don't really see a point in digging through libraries to find something similar.

Comment: Don't do that. You should promisify at the lowest level - `setTimeout` - and move the `func` in a promise callback, where exceptions from it will be properly caught.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the proper **cancellation of promised timeout** similar to `clearTimeout` - returning the promise directly from `setTimeout` is not convenient. Especially when using with [ES7 async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in `try...finally` block. It is better to have separate variable for timeout manipulation. I've implemented this approach as tiny [await-timeout](https://github.com/vitalets/await-timeout) package. It works as following:

```
import Timeout from 'await-timeout';

async function foo() {
  const timeout = new Timeout();
  try {
    const fetchPromise = fetch('https://example.com');
    const timerPromise = timeout.set(1000).then(() => console.log('Timeout!'));
    await Promise.race([fetchPromise, timerPromise]);
  } finally {
    timeout.clear();
  }
}
```

In this example timeout will definitely be cleared in case of fetch success or any error and `console.log('Timeout!')` will not be called.

Comment: This makes no sense. You're only clearing the timeout after having it awaited already…

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!