# Console log Undefined

Tags: angular

console log undefined here

```
      this.http.get(this.rootURL + "/Report/"+id)
      .toPromise().then(res => this.report = res as Report);
      console.log(this.report);
  }
```

here console log the data

```
      this.http.get(this.rootURL + "/Report/"+id)
      .toPromise().then(res => console.log(res));
      console.log(this.report);
  }
```

what can I do to assign result to Result Object

Comment: You need to perform your other operations inside the `then` callback, or use async/await.

Comment: Possible high level duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458201/understanding-javascript-promise-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log your data within the `then` of your [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
this.http.get(this.rootURL + "/Report/"+id)
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => {
    // Promise gets fulfilled and its response can be assigned
    this.report = res as Report;
    console.log(this.report);

    // Perform other actions
    // ...
  })
  .catch(reason => {
    // Something went wrong, your promise gets rejected
    console.log(reason);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using await?

you should be doing something like this:

```js
const main = async () => {
await this.http.get(this.rootURL + "/Report/"+id).toPromise().then(data => {
console.log(data);
})
}
```