# How can I call another api in flat list?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have one API which has title, body, and user-id, and I want to print User Name with the help of another API. So how can I do it?
I have listed both APIs in below.

1. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
2. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1  // ${id}

---

```
getUser(id) {
    let userData = fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        return responseJson.name

      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any

    console.log(userData);
    return userData;
};
```

Comment: I recommend reading about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458201/understanding-javascript-promise-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you can do is first get the posts and save it inside a variable .
then inside a map call other api to get the user data and append the user data in the variable

**example**

```
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',)
        .then(response => {
            let new_post = [];
            let posts =  response.json() ;
            Promise.all(
                posts.map(item => {
                    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+item.userId)
                        .then(res =>{
                            item['user'] = res.json() ;
                            console.log(item)
                            new_post.push(item)
                        })
                })
            )
                .then(() => {
                    this.setState({testing:new_post})
                })
        })
```

then in your flatlist display username by

```
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.testing}
                renderItem={({item}) =>(
                        <View>
                            <Text>other</Text>
                            <Text>{item.user.email}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                }
            />
```

OR if your are using axios to get data change code to

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',)
.then(response => {})
```

Comment: I didn't get any data from response.data. it's 'undefined', what is a change in code please help me

Comment: are you using fetch or axios...?

Comment: if you are using fetch api.. you need to convert the response to json.... I'll edit my answer to show you how fetch and axios works...