# Why does this promise based code return undefined?

Tags: javascript

I want the hello function to return a Promise. Why does it return undefined?

I think the wait function is confusing me. I tried to explain my understanding of it but could not put it in words.

Could someone please explain this to me in very basic terms.

```
    function wait (ms =0){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    })
    }

      async function hello(){
     const nw = await wait(2000);
     console.log(nw);
     }


hello();
```

Comment: `wait` returns a promise. But as you are `await`ing the promise, `nw` is the result of the promise -- in your case `undefined` because you call `resolve` without any parameter -- and not the promise itself.

Comment: Can you please explain the wait function for me. I know how arrow functions work but this is really confusing me.

Comment: So what's the actual question here? How [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s work? How [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) works?

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458201/understanding-javascript-promise-object

Answer (score 1):

Unless you `resolve` with an argument you get nothing. You want:

```
setTimeout(() => { resolve('hello') }, ms);
```

The key here is `setTimeout()` does not give any argument to the function you give it, it just runs it at that time. In this case it's the same as:

```
// Wait ms milliseconds
resolve();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `wait` function returns a promise. But as you are `await`ing it, `nw` is the result of the promise -- in your case `undefined` because you call `resolve` without any parameter -- and not the promise itself.

Your code is (more or less) the same as this

```js
function wait (ms = 0){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(); }, ms)  //Resolve the promise after the given time
  });
}

function hello() {
  wait(2000)
    .then((result) => {
      const nw = result;
      console.log(nw);
    })
   
}
```