# undefined variable comming in fetch api javascript while storing its value in a variable

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>home</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>login here</h1>
<form id="createuserform" method="post">

    <label>First Name: </label>
    <input id="fname" type="test"></br>

    <label>Last Name: </label>
    <input id="lname" type="text"></br>

    <label>Location: </label>
    <input id="location" type="text"></br>

    <input id="createUser" type="button" value="create user"></br>
    <input id="setter" type="text" value="val">
</form>
<script>
    function submitValue() {
        var r;
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/multimediaApi/api/multimedia/users').then(response => (response.json())).then(data => r = data[0]);
        document.getElementById("setter").value = r;
    }
</script>
<button onclick="submitValue()">Get Data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to fetch the data from the above API URL and store it in variable `r`. So, I have used `then(data  => r= data[0])` to assign value to variable `r`. and then display it in `textfield` `document.getElementById("setter").value=r`. But the value the value in r is coming as `undefined`.

Comment: Hello, just to be sure, could you also add a `.catch(e => console.log(e))` onto your call to make sure the fetch request is not erroring out? Also try to log the response you are getting back to make sure it is not undefined, and that it has the right shape for you to access it using `data[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

In the execution of the `submitValue` function, the value of `r` will be `undefined` and initiated a `AJAX` request which will complete sometime later, and the value gets assigned to

```
document.getElementById( "setter" ).value = r;
```

will be `undefined` which is current value of `r`.

---

**`Later some time the request is completed`**

So, the following code runs

```
fetch( 'http://localhost:8080/multimediaApi/api/multimedia/users' )
    .then( response => ( response.json() ) )  // now run
    .then( data => r = data[0] );             // now run
```

In this you are just assigning the `data[0]` to `r`. Rest code already ran before and won't run again. That's how ASYNC JS works.

You should read **[Understanding JavaScript promise object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458201/understanding-javascript-promise-object)**

You can directly assign the `data[0]` to the HTML element with id `setter` as:

```
function submitValue() {
    fetch( 'http://localhost:8080/multimediaApi/api/multimedia/users' )
        .then( response => ( response.json() ) )
        .then(data => {
            document.getElementById( "setter" ).value = data[0];
        })
}
```

Comment: suppose I want to store value of data[0] in a variable and then use it later then for that scenario          .then(data => {
            document.getElementById( "setter" ).value = data[0];
        })   this code is not useful.

Comment: For that scenario you have to lift the state to nearest common parent, where you can declare variable and set the value of the variable in `.then`