# Firebase onAuthStateChanged always returning undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to make a util method which will return either the user object or if the user object exists. With no params it should return a boolean and with the param "getUser" it should return the user object, but it is always returning undefined. This seemed to work for a while, but then I took a break and came back and it was always returning undefined. Code below

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
export default function checkAuthState(type?:string){
    const auth = getAuth()
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
            if(!type) return true
            if(type === "getUser") return user
            else return true
        } else {
            if(!type) return false
            else return false
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: You need to return a [Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320988/9997212).

Answer (score 5):

Your `return true` returns a value to `onAuthStateChanged`, which is what calls your callback. The `onAuthStateChanged` is not doing anything with that value.

If you want to have a promise that resolves once the initial user state has been restored, you can do that with:

```
function checkAuthState(type?:string){
  const auth = getAuth()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        if(!type) resolve(true)
        if(type === "getUser") resolve(user)
        else resolve(true)
      } else {
        if(!type) resolve(false) false
        else resolve(false)
      }
      unsubscribe();
    });
  })
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
checkAuthState().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

Or when using `async`/`await`:

```
const result = await checkAuthState();
console.log(result);
```