# Exporting a boolean variable that depends on an if statement (React JS & Firebase)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to declare a boolean from my firebase.js configuration file that depends on an if-else statement that checks whether a user is logged in or not.

I want to store the log in status of a user in a boolean variable and export that variable across different components in my React app.

So if user is logged in I want my variable isLoggedIn to be true and export that. But I want the isLoggedIn boolean to be updated depending on the log-in status before it gets exported.

Here is my firebase.js file

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    //private keys
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);

//Problem
let isLoggedIn = false;
function checkLoggedInStatus() {
    if (auth.currentUser !== null) { //i.e. user is signed in
        isLoggedIn = true;
    }
    return isLoggedIn;
}

checkLoggedInStatus();

export isLoggedIn;
```

Comment: Where do you call `checkLoggedInStatus`? And you can't reassign a `const`, does just using `let` instead fix the problem?

Comment: You can instead export `checkLoggedInStatus()` and use it wherever required. Also it might be better to use `onAuthStateChanged()` and return a promise as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69875003/13130697)

Comment: @CertainPerformance tried what you said : Unexpected token, expected "{" (32:7)
> 32 | export isLoggedIn;

Comment: Replacing `const` with `let` will not cause a syntax error - you must've made a typo somewhere else too

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have updated my exact code in the original post, no typos it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems here.

---

What immediately follows `export` may be, among other things:

- A declaration followed by a variable name (eg `export let foo = 5;`) - this initializes the variable and exports it from the module in a single line
- `function` or `class` - similar to the above
- `default`, if you want to indicate what you're exporting is the default export
- Brackets, if you're exporting identifiers that have already been declared - eg `export { foo }`

But doing `export isLoggedIn;` is invalid syntax - it falls into none of those categories (nor any of the other permitted constructs).

---

The other issue is that the `.currentUser` property may not exist yet if the auth isn't done initializing. Make sure you wait for it to be done first. Use [the observer version instead](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Since that is asynchronous, you have a few options for getting that information to the rest of your script. The first one, that I'd recommend, is to have this auth module call the rest of your script (in other words, make this module your entry point, or close to it). For example:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { renderApp } from './renderApp';

const firebaseConfig = {
    //private keys
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
        renderApp(user);
    } else {
        // No user
        renderApp();
    }
});
```

where `renderApp` is the starting point for the rest of your code that depends on the user. You can't easily export `isLoggedIn` directly from the firebase module because it's retrieved asynchronously - calling `renderApp` with it and then passing the value around is the best way to do it.

You can also export a Promise from this firebase module script, one that resolves to whether the user is logged in or not, but that'll require all consumers of the module to have to call `.then` on the value before being able to use it, which could be quite messy. Better to use your firebase module script as an entry point and only call the rest of your script once the auth object has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I tried the 
export const isLoggedIn = auth.currentUser !== null;

But when I console.log(isLoggedIn) at any one of my pages, it logs it as false, even though the user is signed in?

Comment: See edit, it looks like your firebase auth object isn't fully initialized at the time this script runs. You'll have to redesign your app so that the auth finishes first before doing anything else in your script.

Comment: could you check the import for renderApp, there doesn't seem to be any './renderApp' library

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you need to restructure your app a bit to account for the asynchronous nature of the auth. That's just an example module where the rest of your app starts from - make *this firebase* module the entry point for your app, and call the rest of your app from here. (Since you haven't shown any of the other code for the app, it's hard to be any more specific - but the idea is to have another module that can run the rest of your app synchronously once you have the login status)

Comment: when you say 'make this firebase module the entry point for your app', could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Don't have any other modules perform side-effects at the top level. Have this firebase module be the first thing that runs in your app, and then have this firebase module import other parts of your app and branch from there. In other words, the control flow should start with this module and branch out to the rest of your app, instead of having different parts of your app start themselves by themselves without being called first.

Comment: I see what you mean now, just not sure if I know how to do that. I have an app.js file which is the current entry point for my app

Comment: You can put the firebase code in that if you want, and then make sure the rest of your app is only called once the user is retrieved. Another option is to call the rest of your app immediately, but with the Firebase data integrated with it - such as with a user state that gets passed down to all children and a `useEffect` that subscribes to `onAuthStateChanged`