# JavaScript setTimeout weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm just trying to return a value after a delay but all I get is the number 1.  If I call the same function again, I get 2, 3, 4, etc so I've made a weird counter but not what I wanted!

```
let wait = n => setTimeout(_ => n, n*1000);
console.log(wait(5));
```

I've tried all the variations I can think of.  Is this some kind of scope problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: Your function is returning the value returned by `setTimeout` which is an identifier of the timeout (an integer), not `n`. If you want to get the `n` value back you need to use an async pattern like a callback or promise.

Comment: Related: [*How to make a promise from setTimeout*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout)

Answer (score 2):

You're returning `n` from the callback you pass to `setTimeout` - not the outside function. In actuality, your `wait` function returns a ID of a timeout returned from `setTimeout`. The only way you can really "delay returning" is to use a Promise and resolve after a timeout:

```
const wait = n => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(n), n * 1000));
```

Then:

```
wait(5).then(n => console.log(n)) //5
```

Then `wait` returns a Promise that resolves in 5 seconds to `n` which you can access via `Promise#then`. With promises, you can also utilize `async` and `await` from ES2016 to get a closer result to what you want:

```
const wait = n => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(n), n * 1000));

(async () => {
  console.log(await wait(5));
})();
```

What `await` does is *await for a promise to resolve*. So `await wait(5)` waits for the promise returned from `wait` to resolve (which is after 5 seconds). Then, it logs the resolved value. You'll also notice it's wrapped in an async immediately executes arrow function. To use `await` you need to be in an `async` function.

Comment: Nice answer (unsurprisingly). I've deleted mine, the above is good and mine mostly duplicated it (unintentionally, but the result is the same). Feel free to grab the async/await stuff (copy and paste if you like) since I know you can see deleted answers. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! I completely forgot about that duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant my answer here duplicated your answer here, not my answer to the related question (nor to the dupetarget). Bergi's pick of a dupetarget is...interesting. A stretch in my view, but it's a matter of degrees, not a matter of kind. (I don't remember voting to close the question, but apparently I did. I wonder what reason I picked.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand, I just forgot the dupe target and should've hammered.

Comment: It's all well-intentioned, which is the main thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your replies.  I thought It might come down to promises.
I was just looking to test a memoize function and all my test functions ran too fast or returned infinity, so was just after a quick hack to slow them down.

Comment: @Li357 thank your for your reply too.

Comment: JavaScript code is so long winded & cumbersome.