# Why `async/await` doesn't work in my case?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I read about `async/await`, but I've a critical question.
At first I explain an old example to show base of my question and then I ask my exact question.

Everybody know it:

```
console.log('1');
console.log('2');
console.log('3'); // Ex: 123
```

It is simple but in below case:

```
console.log('1');
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('2');
},0);
console.log('3'); // Ex: 132
```

It is simple too, `setTimeout` function is `asynchronous` and `JavaScript` jump from it and after resolve run its function, so we see `2` after `1` and `3`.

But, now I read `async/await` and I wrote a function like this:

```
(async function test() {
    console.log('1');
    await setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('2');
    },0);
    console.log('3');
})(); // Ex: 132
```

The Export is `132` too, why? this is my question, why `3` run before `2`? I expect because of `async/await` after `1` JavaScript wait for `2` and then wrote `3`. why `132`?

Comment: async functions are part of ES2017, not ES7 (ES2016).

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks, I'm confusing, is `ES2017` called `ES8`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`await` only suspends when the value passed to it is a `Promise`. In your case, `setTimeout` returns a `Number` so await doesn't wait for it.

The correct code will be as follows:

```
async function test() {
    console.log('1');
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('2');
            resolve()
        }, 0);
    });
    console.log('3');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise. `await x` only waits if `x` is a promise; if `x` isn't a promise, it's (effectively) wrapped in one as though you had `await Promise.resolve(x)`. That means the code following it will run asynchronously but as soon as possible.*

If you want a promise version of `setTimeout`, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout). But even with that, your `test` function wouldn't use a callback, instead you'd just await the promise-enabled timeout:

```js
function later(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

async function test() {
  console.log("1");
  await later(10);
  console.log("2");
  console.log("3");
}

test().catch(e => console.error(e));
console.log("After the call (just to prove it does wait for the timeout after 1 and before 2");
```

---

* On browsers, that's guaranteed to be before a `setTimeout(..., 0)` scheduled during the same task, because promise callbacks scheduled during a task occur just after the end of that task, before the next task is picked up from the queue (even if the next task was scheduled before the promise callback). More on this ("macrotasks" and "microtasks") in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915634/difference-between-microtask-and-macrotask-within-an-event-loop-context).

Answer (score 1):

You can `await` to that functions that returns `Promise`. `setTimeout` does not returns `Promise`. So in this case `await` used before the `setTimeout` does not has a sense.

You can wrap your `setTimeout` into a Promise and call resolve at the `setTimeout` function.

```js
(async function test() {
    console.log('1');
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
         setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('2');
            resolve(); // also can pass a parameter here to get it via await.
         },0);
    });
    console.log('3');
})();
```