# async/await function does not wait for setTimeout to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm using await within an async function execute functions in a particular order, if you see here - I wanted `startAnim` to wait until `hideMoveUI` had finished executing to execute itself.

Though my console log returns:

```
startAnim
hideMoveUI
```

My code:

```
async function printAll() {
  await hideMoveUI();
  await startAnim();
}
printAll();

hideMoveUI = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('hideMoveUI');
    }, 3000);
  }

startAnim =() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('startAnim');
    }, 500);
  }
```

Is `setTimeout` an `async` function?

How can I make the second function wait for the first one to finish? any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: printAll()
 .then(() => hideMoveUI())
 .then(() => startAnim =())

Comment: @Rajesh: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: It's ES2017, not ES7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your `hideMoveUI`/`startAnim` functions have no return value, so calling them results in `undefined`. `await undefined` is `undefined`.
2. If you fix #1, `await` would be waiting on a timer handle, which on browsers is a number. There's no way for `await` to know that number is a timer handle.

Instead, [give yourself a promise-enabled `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout) and use it.

E.g.:

```js
const wait = (delay, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, ...args));

const hideMoveUI = () => {
  return wait(3000).then(() => console.log('hideMoveUI'));
};

const startAnim = () => {
  return wait(500).then(() => console.log('startAnim'));
};
  
async function printAll() {
  await hideMoveUI();
  await startAnim();
}
printAll()
  .catch(e => { /*...handle error...*/ });
```

or of course

```js
const wait = (delay, ...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay, ...args));

const hideMoveUI = async () => {
  await wait(3000);
  console.log('hideMoveUI');
};

const startAnim = async () => {
  await wait(500);
  console.log('startAnim');
};
  
async function printAll() {
  await hideMoveUI();
  await startAnim();
}
printAll()
  .catch(e => { /*...handle error...*/ });
```