# Async Await unusual behaviour

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to understand JavaScript Async/Await feature.

So I wrote a short code to understand it but it is giving me unusual behaviour/result.

```js
var a = 10;

function load_data(data) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    a = data
  }, 2000);
}

function print() {
  console.log(a);
}

async function init() {
  await load_data(40);
  print();
}

init();
```

I expect the value logged to be 40, but its logging 10 with async and await.

Comment: `await load_data(40);` evaluates to `await undefined`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [async/await function does not wait for setTimeout to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813405/async-await-function-does-not-wait-for-settimeout-to-finish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async [await depends on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), but you aren't making a promise anywhere in your code. As a result, awaiting `load_data` doesn't wait.

Try using a promise and resolving once the timeout fires:

```
function load_data(data){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        a=data
        resolve()
    }, 2000))
}
```

Also, we'll assume this is just for learning async/await…otherwise you should consider all the usual advice agains using global variables this way. It's a recipe for a mess once your code gets any larger

```js
var a = 10

function load_data(data){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        a=data
        resolve()
    }, 2000))
}

function print(){
    console.log(a)
}

async function init(){
    await load_data(40);
    print();
}

init();
```

Answer (score 2):

Async/Await is syntax used for handling promises, not just any asynchronous behavior. For it to work with `load_data`, the function would need to return a promise object that resolves 40.

This should work how you expect:

```
var a = 10

function load_data(data){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        a=data;
        resolve(a);
    }, 2000)
  });
}

function print(){
    console.log(a)
}

async function init(){

    await load_data(40);

    print();
}

init();
```

Before learning about async await, learning about promises is essential since it's just a syntax over promises.

Answer (score 2):

You should return a `Promise` in `load_data()`. Actually you're returning nothing, so the code is not waiting for any value to be resolved. You should do something like this:

```
function load_data(data){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           a=data;
           resolve(true);
       }, 2000)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should create the promise. Furthermore, it is better not to use a global variable, but to let the promise resolve with the desired value:

```js
function load_data(data){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(data); //<-- pass data to resolve
        }, 2000)
    });
}

async function init(){
    let data = await load_data(40); // <--- get the promised value
    console.log(data);
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

please set promise for the set your value before execute print function

```
var a = 10;
function load_data(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      a=data;
      resolve('resolved');
  });
}

async function init() {

  var result = await load_data(40);
  print();
}

function print(){
    console.log(a)
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [manual1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) [manual2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

It's work for me:

```
var a = 10

function load_data(data){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            a=data;
            resolve('ok');
           }, 2000)    
});

}

function print(){
    console.log(a)
}

async function init(){

await load_data(40);

print();
}

init();
```