# Why await is not waiting

Tags: javascript

How to wait for setTimeout to complete first

```js
function a() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('should wait');
  }, 5000);
}
async function b(c) {
  console.log('hello');
  await c();
}
b(a);
console.log('out');
```

My expected output is

> Hello

> should wait

> out

Comment: setTimeout does not use promises.

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous. Other code will run while the timeout "waits" to execute the callback you pass to it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813405/async-await-function-does-not-wait-for-settimeout-to-finish

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async/await function does not wait for setTimeout to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813405/async-await-function-does-not-wait-for-settimeout-to-finish)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not return a Promise and `await` only works with Promises.

Also, put the `console.log("out")` inside the `b` function for it to run after the `a` function.

Check the code snippet below, it does what you were looking for.

```js
function a() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('should wait');
      res();
    }, 5000);
  })
}
async function b(c) {
  console.log('hello');
  await c();
  console.log('out');
}
b(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function must return a promise if you want example to work properly (await keywords "awaits" for returned promise to resolve): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

You example should look like:

```
function a() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
  });
}

async function b(c) {
  console.log('hello');
  await c();
  console.log('should wait');
}
await b(a);
console.log('out');
```

Note that you can use `await` keyword on function, because declaring function as async automatically makes it return a promise.