# Async/await executing all immediately

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Quite new to coding in general and not used async/await much before.
I'm trying to get an enemy in a little maze game I'm making to move up, left, down, right, repeat.

Problem I have is that the function just executes everything at once instead of waiting. I know I'm missing something, but can't put my finger on it. Can anyone advise?

```
async function enemyMovement() {
  enemyCSSVertical = -50;
  enemyCSSHorizontal = 400;
  enemyX = 9;
  enemyY = 10;
  await enemyUp();
  await enemyLeft();
  await enemyDown();
  await enemyRight();
}

// move up
async function enemyUp() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("up");
    enemyCSSVertical += -50;
    enemy.css("top", enemyCSSVertical);
  }, 1000);
}

//move left
async function enemyLeft() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("left");
    enemyCSSHorizontal += -50;
    enemy.css("left", enemyCSSHorizontal);
  }, 1000);
}

async function enemyDown() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("down");
    enemyCSSVertical += 50;
    enemy.css("top", enemyCSSVertical);
  }, 1000);
}

async function enemyRight() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("right");
    enemyCSSHorizontal += 50;
    enemy.css("left", enemyCSSHorizontal);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing waiting for any of these `setTimeout`s to be finished and `async` doesn’t magically change the semantics of `setTimeout`. See [How to make a promise from setTimeout](/q/22707475/4642212).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [async/await function does not wait for setTimeout to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813405/async-await-function-does-not-wait-for-settimeout-to-finish)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a promise in your move functions and resolve it within the timeout

```
async function enemyUp() {
  var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("up");
      enemyCSSVertical += -50;
      enemy.css("top", enemyCSSVertical);
      resolve("Finished");
    }, 1000);
  }
  return p;
}
```