# setTimeout() and clearTimeout() with Promise in TypeScript (strict mode + all annotations)

Tags: node.js, typescript, timer, promise

I saw many examples of timer with Promise for JavaScript. Most of them are too complicated, but I suppose, it could be implemented more simply. However, I need the solution for TypeScript in `"strict": true` mode with all annotations.

I tried to do it until below code:

```js
import Timeout = NodeJS.Timeout;

let testTimeout : Timeout;
const DELAY: number = 3000;

testTimeout = (): Promise<void> => (
  new Promise<void>( (resolve): void => {
    setTimeout(resolve, DELAY);
  })
);

testTimeout = testTimeout().then( () => {
  console.log('done');
});
clearTimeout(testTimeout);
```

It has errors:

```
TS2739: Type '() => Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'Timeout': ref, refresh, unref

TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Timeout' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I suppose, I do something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function setTimeoutPromise(fn: () => number, delay: number): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(fn())
        }, delay)
    })
}

setTimeoutPromise(() => {
    console.log('resolving...');
    return 10;
}, 5000).then((res) => console.log('should print 10 after 5 secs', res));
```

this compiles fine with `tsc --strict true`. I am not sure if this what you are looking for though. Let me know!

There is another way of achieving this that I have just thought about:

```
import * as util from 'util';

const setTimeoutPromise = util.promisify((delay, fn) => setTimeout(fn, delay));
setTimeoutPromise(5000).then(() => console.log('hey you!'));
```

It might look a bit strange but it works. Basically `.promisify` expects a standard callback-last function to be passed to it as an argument where as the `setTimeout` has the opposite signature. So we reverse them:)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I did not understand from the first example, how to do `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Please add how to use clearTimeout or remove it. The standard setTimout as promise has been answered somewhere else. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout