# Recursive function for checking local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an application on a react. It has two modules: one that sets `true` value in `localStorage`, the second that runs the code and then sets `false` value to `localStorage`

I am trying to check as follows:

```
localStorage.setItem('update', false);

const checkUpdate = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('update') == 'true') {
    localStorage.setItem('update', false)
    alert('SUCCESFUL')
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}


if (checkUpdate() == true) {
  console.log('OK')
} else {
  setTimeout(checkUpdate(), 2000)
}
```

It just does not work, and I can’t understand what my mistake is

Comment: `setTimeout(checkUpdate(), 2000)` will invoke `checkUpdate` immediately. If you want to only call it 2 seconds later, then remove the invocation: `setTimeout(checkUpdate, 2000)`

Comment: You have to get your types right... `true != 'true'` The first is a boolean, whereas the second is a string

Comment: @devnull69 pulling from localStorage always results in a string. That's why many devs opt for JSON in localStorage instead

Comment: @devnull69 not sure why this is relevant here - if you take anything from localStorage it's turned into a string

Comment: ... and there is no code that sets the value to true or 'true' in localStorage

Comment: @devnull69 sure, but OP's conditional is correct, they do not have the types wrong

Comment: It just hurts to see someone setting a boolean value to localStorage in the first place. I always tell people to only set strings to avoid complications and ambiguities

Comment: You might consider using a promise to reduce the potential of having multiple calls stack up as examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22707551/125981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout(checkUpdate(), 2000)` will simply evaluate to `setTimeout(false, 2000)` on the first run because you are calling the function and not passing the referal to the `setTimeout`. The solution would be to use `setTimeout(checkUpdate, 2000)`.

However, instead of always setting `setTimeout()`, you can use a `setInterval()` and when the condition meets, simply stop the interval with `clearInterval()`.

```
localStorage.setItem('update', false);

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('update') == 'true') {
    // stop the interval
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert('SUCCESSFUL');
  } else {
    console.log('not yet, retrying');
  }
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => localStorage.setItem('update', true), 5000);
```

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/vajuxuyifa/edit?js,console)