# sleep inside a for loop and a finally block

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently have the following loop

```
for (const pk of likerpk)
{
     await likeMediaId(ig, pk.trim());

}
```

the issue is that i wanted to call likeMediaId every X seconds and after the whole likeMediaId is done I wanted to call the function called Y

I have tried putting a sleep inside a for loop but that does not help, it seems that it is still executing likeMediaId in parallel, while i always want to execute 1 likeMediaId at a time

basically the flow that i wanted is (assuming 3 items in the array)

```
likeMediaId()
sleep 60 seconds
likeMediaId()
sleep 60 seconds
likeMediaId()
sleep 60 seconds

call function Y
```

what is the most elegant way in doing this?

Comment: you could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout in combination with what you alredy have, and control both with a Promise.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: const { promisify } = require('util'); const sleep = promisify(setTimeout); /* later in the loop: */ await sleep(60000);

Comment: Most elegant way is code it not in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you're open to rxjs:

```
const likeMediaId$ = (pk) => from(likeMediaId(ig, pk.trim())); // observable from promise
from(likerpk).pipe( // observable stream from list items
  concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(60000))) // wait 60 seconds
  switchMap(pk => likeMediatId$(pk)), // run the function
  finally(() => Y()) // at end, do this
).subscribe(
  result => console.log(result),
  error => console.log(error)
)
```

wana go super vanilla? why not try an interval?

```
let i = likerpk.length // counter
const clearInterval = setInterval(() => {
  i -= 1 // iterate
  await likeMediaId(likerPk[i]) // await (runs backwards)
  if (!i) { // out of items
    clearInterval() // clear
    Y() // run Y
  }
}, 60000) // every 60 seconds
```

Comment: i think you shouldnt assign i as a constant if we were going to i -= 1

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a little helper:

```
// a little utility
const delay = (delay) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

for (const pk of likerpk)
{
     await likeMediaId(ig, pk.trim());
     await delay(60000);
}

Y();
```

> it seems that it is still executing likeMediaId in parallel

Then this is an error in your function `likeMediaId`. It seems to resolve before the work is done. That's the only way all iterations could run basically in paralell.

Answer (score -1):

you could use a timeout to do it. Maybe it's not the most elegant, but should work fine.

```
var i=0;

async function cycle() {
    await likeMediaId(ig, likerpk[i].trim());
    i++;
    if (i < likerpk.length) {
        setTimeout(cycle, 1000);
    }
}

cycle();
```