# Why Promises are resolving in the same time in async/await

Tags: javascript

So as I mentioned in the title - why this two `Promises` are resolving in the same time? Shouldn't `const a` wait `1000 ms` for resolving `p` and then `const b` resolve after that in `1000 ms` as well?

```js
const p = new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(() => res(10), 1000)
})
const p1 = new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(() => res(100), 1000)
})

const resolve = async () => {
  const a = await p;
  console.log(a)
  const b = await p1;
  console.log(b)
}

resolve();
```

They both do `console.log` in the same time. I expect:

```
wait 1000ms
console.log(10)
wait 1000ms
console.log(100)
```

Comment: The promise callback doesn’t _start_ running at `await`. They start at `new Promise(`…`)`.

Comment: Consider making `p` and `p1` functions? Then the promises are created when the functions are called.

Comment: The answer you are looking for may be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout