# how console.log1234 in synchronous way

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, synchronous

How can I console 1234 in this function. using await or async. Now it logs 1243. It should wait before the 3 then log the 4.

```js
    function Call(){
     console.log('1');
     console.log('2');
     setTimeout(()=>console.log('3'),1000);
     console.log('4');
    }
    Call();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a promise from setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout). Then all you need to do is await the third log.

Comment: "fix this" is not an appropriate way to talk to people here.

Comment: Also please note that using async/await does not make the code synchronous.

Comment: I suspect English is your second (or third, or fourth) language, but so you know, saying "fix this" to people is very rude in every English-speaking culture I've experienced. (It **might** be okay for a boss talking to an employee, but even then, it's a bit harsh; and that's not at all the situation here.) Instead, ask *how* to fix it: "How do I fix this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the key here is to create a promise-based `setTimeout` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout):

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Then make your function an `async` function and `await` the timeout:

```
async function call(){
    console.log('1');
    console.log('2');
    await delay(1000);
    console.log('3');
    console.log('4');
}
call();
```

Normally, you want to handle errors, but we know the above can't throw any, so...

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function call(){
    console.log('1');
    console.log('2');
    await delay(1000);
    console.log('3');
    console.log('4');
}
call();
```

> how console.log1234 in synchronous way

Note that the above makes the *logic* in the function synchronous, but the code does not execute synchronously. `call` returns as of the `await`, and then resumes later when the timer fires and settles the promise.