# How to promise.race an array of async/sync callbacks vs a timeout when both are ran in parallel

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a set of callbacks that may run on different durations before I close my web app. I also have a timeout where if it reaches past the timeout duration, I also close the application. The reason for this is to prevent the callbacks from blocking in closing the web app if it passes timeout duration.

Here is my current solution:

```
  public close() {
      const callbacks = this.onBeforeCloseCallbacks.map((cb) => new Promise(res => res(cb())));
      const timeout = new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, TIMEOUT_DURATION));
      await Promise.race([Promise.all(callbacks), timeout]).then((value) => {
        // Currently returns Promise.all(callbacks) right away
        console.log(value)
      });
      await this.pluginEngine.close();
    }
  }
```

These are my tests

```
it('Should still close the plugin when timing out', async () => {
  // Arrange
  const cleanupMock = jest.fn();
  const cb1 = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(async () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log('cb1')), 3000)));
  const cleanupMock2 = jest.fn();
  const cb2 = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(async () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log('cb2')), 11000)));
  const placementCloseService = new PlacementCloseService(integrationMock, pluginInterface);

  // Act
  // onBeforeClose is registering callbacks that needs to be run before close
  placementCloseService.onBeforeClose(cb1);
  placementCloseService.onBeforeClose(cb2);
  await placementCloseService.close();

  // Assert
  expect(cleanupMock).toBeCalled();
  expect(cleanupMock2).not.toBeCalled();
  expect(pluginInterface.context.close).toBeCalled();
});
```

My current solution is returning `Promise.all(callbacks)` even if it hasn't called expected callbacks to run yet. What I expect to happen is that it passes through my `timeout` instead since it has a timer of 4000 and the last closeCallback has a timer of 5000.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"For some context `cb: () => Promise<void>`"* Not with the code in the question. In the code in the question, `cb`'s type would be `cb: (async: any) => number` (on browsers). Those aren't `async` functions. ([Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout/22707551#22707551).) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Your title says "*array of sync callbacks*" - if they are really synchronous, then it is impossible to race a timeout against them. Or was that a typo?

Comment: @Bergi the callbacks could be async and sync as it’s coming from multiple services. How would I ensure then if the callbacks that are running past my timeout duration, I would still run my close method? I need this so it won’t block the application from closing when running these callbacks

Comment: Just don't write synchronous code that blocks for a long time in your callbacks. There's really no way to stop them if you had such synchronous callbacks.

Comment: hmm true but how do we cover the async callbacks though

Comment: Just like you did - the code with `Promise.race` is fine. What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. Here is a fiddle I made and it doesn't resolve Promise.race for me on either timeout or Promise.all(callbacks) https://jsfiddle.net/g8cp9ams/1/ @Bergi

Comment: @deathknight256 That's throwing "*TypeError: cb is not a function*" because your array of callbacks is not an array of functions but an array of promises, so it never gets to construct the `timeout` promise and call `Promise.race`. Once that is fixed, [it works as it should](https://jsfiddle.net/92o0crhd/).

Answer (score 1):

Your `closeCallbacks` are not async, You need them to return a `promise`.

```
const closeCallbacks = [
  // for sample purposes. i assigned timeouts to mock that it takes longer to run these callbacks then my timeout duration
  async () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log('cb1')), 3000)),
  async () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log('cb2')), 5000)),
];
```

Comment: Hello! I updated my comment on closeCallbacks. Sorry. The timeouts are merely an example and a real world scenario these are just functions being run but may take time more than my timeoutDuration. Would it still be the same case and I need to wrap them in a promise before I push them to my callback array?

Comment: @deathknight256 - Much better to provide a [mre] with mocked functions actually returning promises.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a parameter named `async` not an async function

```
(async) => {}
```

Your `timeout` function never calls `res` parameter

```
const wait = (cb, time) => new Promise(r => { cb(); r() }, time)

const closeCallbacks = [
  () => wait(() => console.log('cb1'), 3000),
  () => wait(() => console.log('cb2'), 5000)
];

const timeout = new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'); res(), 4000));
```

Comment: Hello! I updated my comment on closeCallbacks. Sorry. The timeouts are merely an example and a real world scenario these are just functions being run but may take time more than my timeoutDuration. Would it still be the same case and I need to wrap them in a promise before I push them to my callback array?